# Trouble converting javascript string to number

Tags: javascript

I have a script assigns a variable using parseFloat as follows:

```
var vendorCost = parseFloat(vendorSearchresults[0].getValue('vendorcost')).toFixed(2);
```

I assumed this would make the variable a number.  However when I check it with typeof - it reports it as a string.  My solution is as follows:

```
vendorCost = parseFloat(vendorCost);
```

Which works, however I'm trying to be more efficient when coding and would like to understand why it doesn't make vendorCost a number when assigning it a number? Is there a way I could make the first statement make vendorCost a number without the need for the second statement?  Thanks in advance.

Update - just thought I should mention I'm having the exact same issue without using .toFixed -

```
    var vendorLandedCost = parseFloat(vendorSearchresults[0].getValue('custentity_asg_landed_cost','vendor'));
    vendorLandedCost = parseFloat(vendorLandedCost);
```

Answer (score 1):

The last toFixed() call converts the result of the first parseFloat into a string.

Looks like you need to round the number to two decimal places, which is why you're using the parseFloat call. You can do something like this instead:

```
vendor_cost = Math.round(parseFloat(vendorSearchresults[0].getValue('vendorcost')) * 100) / 100
```

Comment: Just added an example of the same exact thing happening without using toFixed.

Comment: @ASGJim: Did you check that `parseFloat(vendorSearchresults[0].getValue('custentity_asg_landed_cost','vendor'));` is indeed a string?

Comment: Yes.  Before I added `vendorLandedCost = parseFloat(vendorLandedCost);` it returned string.  After I added that statement it returns number.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Number.toFixed` returns string because it is a data presentation function.

See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).